# Ascii Art in Python not printing in one line

Tags: python, function, for-loop, ascii, ascii-art

```
s = [0,2,6,4,7,1,5,3]


def row_top():
    print("|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|")

def cell_left():
   print("| ", end = "")

def solution(s):
   for i in range(8):
       row(s[i])

def cell_data(isQ):
   if isQ:
      print("X", end = "")
      return ()
   else:
      print(" ", end = "")


def row_data(c):
   for i in range(9):
      cell_left()
      cell_data(i == c)

def row(c):
   row_top()
   row_data(c)
   print("\n")


solution(s)
```

I'm trying to make a chess board, but the cell left keeps printing in separate lines. Also the spaces in between the | is needed, but it need to be next to the |. *FIXED*

*NEW PROBLEM*
Now my out put has a space every two lines and I have updated the code above.

The output is suppose to look like this:

```
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
|  |  |  |  |  | X|  |  |
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
|  |  | X|  |  |  |  |  |
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
|  |  |  |  | X|  |  |  | 
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  | X|
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
| X|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
|  |  |  | X|  |  |  |  |
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
|  | X|  |  |  |  |  |  |
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
|  |  |  |  |  |  | X|  |
|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|
```

I know this chess board isn't very square but this is only a rough draft at the moment.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question! Don't edit the question so the given answers no longer make sense.  I am rolling back that edit.

Comment: I case you didn't understand, I meant ask a [totally new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  Not only does modifying this existing one to ask a totally new question not follow the protocal of this site, *no one* will answer it because there is already an answer to this question.  You will do yourself a favor by actually following my instructions (assuming you actually want the question answered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print()` in Python 3 prints newlines unless you tell it not to. Pass in `end=''` to tell it not to print that newline:

```
def row_top():
    print("|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|")

def cell_left():
     print("| ", end='')

def cell_data(isQ):
     if isQ:
        print("X", end='')
    else:
        print(" ", end='')

def row(c):
    row_top()
    row_data(c)
    print("|")
```

Comment: Assuming OP is using the print function (which seems reasonable here).  If it's actually a print statement with superfluous parenthesis, then newline suppression is achieved by adding a trailing comma.

Comment: It worked Thanks!, but I have a new problem, now in between each line I have a space.